# React Native limit characters

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working with the API.

```
renderGridItem = (itemData) => {
 return(
  <Text>
   {itemData.item.description}
  </Text>
 );
};
```

I want to show only the first 50 characters of the description. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use regular javascript functions to do that. In this case [substring](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

```
renderGridItem = (itemData) => {
 return(
  <Text>
   {itemData.item.description.substring(0, 50)}
  </Text>
 );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Welcome @Nai to StackOverflow,

You may use the pure JavaScript functions. `slice` or maybe `substring`.

Use of Slice:-

```js
renderGridItem = (itemData) => {
 return(
  <Text>
   {itemData.item.description.slice(0, 50)}
  </Text>
 );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly 50 characters, but you could achieve this with a combination of:

- Declare `numberOfLines` prop for text and set it to 1 / 2 (depending on your needs).
- Declare `ellipsizeMode` with whatever you want it to be.
- Set width of the container / text itself to the width you need and want to display.

[Link to docs on Text in React Native.](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#ellipsizemode)

This way you're making sure that your text is going to show correctly and no word is going to be cut in an ugly way.